# How to GROUP BY without breaking order?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a very simple ordered table with the following data:

```
=============================
|   Timestamp  |    Count   |
=============================
|   12/30/2016 |    322     |
|   12/29/2016 |    322     |
|   12/28/2016 |    322     |
|   12/4/2016  |    541     |
|   12/3/2016  |    541     |
|   12/2/2016  |    541     |
|   12/1/2016  |    322     |
|   11/30/2016 |    322     |
|   11/29/2016 |    322     |
=============================
```

I would like to `SELECT MAX([Timestamp]), Count FROM [dbo].[Table] GROUP BY [Count]` without breaking `[Timestamp]` order, i.e. the output should be:

```
=============================
|   Timestamp  |    Count   |
=============================
|   12/30/2016 |    322     |
|   12/4/2016  |    541     |
|   12/1/2016  |    322     |
=============================
```

So `12/1/2016 | 322` is not hidden by the `GROUP BY`. 
Does anybody know how to write such query? I need an EntityFramework Linq query and it would be great to know a T-SQL analogue.

Comment: group by Count and geting max doesn't work?!?

Comment: @Damirchi no, because it will hide the second `322` value

Comment: you said "max timestamp for each count" and there most be one 322 not more

Comment: If you want the max time stamp for each count then why do you want the second 322?

Comment: @RabidPenguin ok, fixed the definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a query like this:

```
select [Timestamp], [Count]
from (
    select *
        --//Step 3: Now just find the max value
        , row_number() over (partition by seqGroup order by [Timestamp] desc) as seq
    from (
        select *
            --//Step 2: you need to generate a group number for each sequence
            , sum(changed) over (order by [Timestamp] desc) as seqGroup
        from (
            select *
                --//Step 1: you need to track changes over [Count]
                , case when coalesce(lag([Count]) over (order by [Timestamp] desc), [Count]) = [Count] then 0 else 1 end as changed
            from yourTable ) t1
        ) t2
    ) t3
where seq = 1;
```

Comment: Looks like this query works perfectly! Thanks a lot. Do you know a Linq analogue?

Comment: I'm not really good at LinQ, But now you can ask for a LinQ for this query ;).

Answer (score 0):

I see previous answer, and on the his basis written LINQ request.

**1)** Create you initTable:

```
var initTable = new List<Tuple<DateTime, int>>();
                initTable.Add(Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2016, 12, 30), 322));
                initTable.Add(Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2016, 12, 29), 322));
                initTable.Add(Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2016, 12, 28), 322));
                initTable.Add(Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2016, 12, 4), 541));
                initTable.Add(Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2016, 12, 3), 541));
                initTable.Add(Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2016, 12, 2), 541));
                initTable.Add(Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2016, 12, 1), 322));
                initTable.Add(Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2016, 11, 30), 322));
                initTable.Add(Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2016, 11, 29), 322));
```

**2)** Add row index in initTable and order by Timestamp:

```
//get row index
var table = initTable
            .Where(x => true)
            .Select((x, i) => new 
            {
                Timestamp = x.Item1.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"), 
                Count = x.Item2,
                //row index
                Index = i
            })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp);
```

**3)** Query

```
var query = table
            //#1 get prev row count
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Timestamp,
                x.Count,
                x.Index,
                //previous row count (-1 for first row, not default null)
                Prev = table.LastOrDefault(y => y.Index < x.Index) == null ? 
                       -1 : 
                       table.LastOrDefault(y => y.Index < x.Index).Count
            })
            //#2 set group flag
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Timestamp,
                x.Count,
                x.Index,
                x.Prev,
                GroupId = x.Count == x.Prev
            })
            //#3
            .Where(x => x.GroupId == false)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Timestamp,
                x.Count
            });
```

You can insert it into LinqPad and verify result.

I hope this will be helpfully.